# Script loaded only on home page appears on other routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using the Zendesk Webwidget, and it seems like the script that I'm adding and showing only on the Home page is loaded on other pages as well if I load those pages first on the browser.

Expected behavior: Going directly to the help route/component should not load the Zendesk WebWidget script until routing to the home page.

Gotten behavior: Going directly to the help route/component loads the Zendesk WebWidget.

Here's some sample code:

Routes:

```
const AppRoutes = () => (
  <AppContainer>
   <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/help" component={Help} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
   </Switch>
  </AppContainer>
);
```

Home:

```
const zendeskWidget = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://myzendeskscript.com';
  script.setAttribute('id', 'ze-snippet');
  script.async = true;
  script.addEventListener('load', function () {
    resolve();
  });
  script.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    reject(e);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});

class Home extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    zendeskWidget.then(() => {
      // code to show the widget when coming back to the home page
      if(zE && zE.show) {
        zE.show();
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    zendeskWidget.then(() => {
      // code to hide the widget when leaving home page
      if(zE && zE.hide) {
        zE.hide();
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <HomeContainer />
    );
  }
};
```

Help:

```
const Help = () => (
  <HelpContainer>
    Some Text
  </HelpContainer>
);
```

Comment: It's going to load the component when you load the react app by the nature of single page applications. Since your zendeskWidget const is defined outside of lifecycle hooks, it'll load the script when it loads the component. If you don't want this behavior, you're going to have to move the script load into the lifecycle hooks somewhere.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this helped you, I guess I'll put it as an answer.

It's going to load the component when you load the react app by the nature of single page applications. Since your zendeskWidget const is defined outside of lifecycle hooks, it'll load the script when it loads the component. If you don't want this behavior, you're going to have to move the script load into the lifecycle hooks somewhere.

Comment: Was about to ask you to post it as an answer, thanks again!